# Web API to external receipt printer

Tags: api, http, printing, pos

I've created an endpoint that displays full order details. The plan is to send a request to the endpoint which will automatically print off. Is there a receipt printer that exists that can connect to the internet (via wifi preferably) and continuously check for new requests and print if need be?

I know there are POS systems that exist but I just want a standalone printer that checks for requests via the web.

Comment: Have You figured it out yet ?
I'm in the same situation with multiple receipts printers

Comment: I didn't unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this as well, to me it seems like CloudPRNT enabled printers from Star Micronics can do exactly this. You configure it to poll a certain web endpoint and it can then be instructed to print.

Star Micronics don't seem to require you to be a partner to them to do so. I think that both Brother and Epson has printers with similar capabilities (search for cloud printing and POS) but you they want you to be a partner to even get the developer documentation.

https://star-emea.com/products/mc-print3/